# What is the framework in which we can talk about the procedure of Richard's paradox rigorously?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, real-numbers, diagonalization, paradoxes

It seems there are two variants of [Richard's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard%27s_paradox): one pertaining to natural language and one pertaining to first-order logic. I will focus on the latter.

Now as [pointed out in this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/44129), there are a few issues when it comes to talking about definable real numbers. First, you can't define the notion of a definable real number from within FOL. Second, it seems like whether something is definable or not is relative to the theory that you are starting with. These seem to be enough to circumvent Richard's paradox, but it still seems like I can still start with a theory and use Richard's paradox to construct a new real number.

Here I will informally outline my construction. I am wondering how I would be able to do this rigorously.

1. Lexicographically order all FOL formulas $\varphi$ that specify a unique real number $x$.
2. Number the items in the list so that these real numbers are placed into a sequence $x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots$.
3. Apply Cantor diagonalization to the sequence to obtain a new real number $x$ distinct from $x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots$.

Now I know this cannot be done in FOL and ZFC. My question is, in what extension to FOL and ZFC could I make this procedure to obtain this new real number $x$ (described by a system outside of initial system)? Can anyone give me any clues?

Comment: I think you can do it in FOL and ZFC in the way you described. What do you think the problem is?

Comment: @Karl As far as I understand, the concept of a definable real number is not something definable in FOL, so the sequence in #2 can't be defined naively.

Comment: Oh, by "in FOL and ZFC" did you not mean "diagonalizing over FOL formulas, but carrying out the construction in ZFC"?

Comment: @Karl Preferably yes, but again I'm not sure if that makes any sense (I have limited knowledge in this domain).

Comment: Before even step 1 you need to have the set of all formulas that specify a unique real number. The rest of the steps are as easy as you say.

Comment: You don't need real numbers.  The undescribable object can be finite, like a string or integer.  "The smallest integer that cannot be described in 10 words."

Comment: @DanielV This is only true if we restrict the description (for example by the allowed length).

Comment: I think it works fine as described. In step 1, you need to choose a [signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signature_(logic)) for your first-order language and a corresponding [structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structure_(mathematical_logic)) (presumably based on $\Bbb R$) in which you're evaluating the formulas to determine whether they uniquely specify a real number. This can all be carried out in ZF. You end up with a ZF-definable real number that is not definable in your chosen first-order language

Comment: Also, since ZFC is a first-order theory, you can even use a model of set theory as the structure in question, so that you diagonalize over formulas that express set-theoretic constructions. Then you end up specifying (via a complicated formula $\psi$ in the metatheory, which is also set theory) an element $r$ of the model's internal version of $\Bbb R$ that is not definable inside the structure. Interpreted inside the structure, $\psi$ refers to a "model inside the model" and thereby uniquely defines a number internally, but this is necessarily different from $r$.

Comment: As mentioned by Karl, definability in a model works to formalize this, but an important caveat is we have to be sure the model will contain the undefinable object and only fail to define it. For some choice of model, there will be real numbers not present in the model, even if the model appears set-theoretically "rich". E.g. Godel's model $L$ satisfies all axioms of ZFC and so may appear suitable, but there is a real number called "[$0^\sharp$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_sharp)" which, if it exists, is not even a member of $L$ to begin with. (ZFC can't even prove $0^\sharp$ exists)